# Notify Slack when the Azure App service swap is complete

Tags: azure, slack, swap

Is there a way to get notified in Slack when the Azure App service's auto-swap operation finishes? I would like to be notified both when the swap succeeds and when it fails.

The swap itself takes about 2-3 minutes,
so I would like to be notified in Slack when the swap is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Event grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-app-service?tabs=event-grid-event-schema) to listen to the event `Microsoft.Web/sites.SlotSwapCompleted`, then you can create [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-webhooks) to send notification into slack

Answer (score 0):

Build an alert that triggers on the event in the activity log, and then use an action group associated with the alert to send a notification to Slack.